# Regular expression in Javascript to find specific value

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a Javascript variable:

```
var Mytemp = 
“<”span class="ic_evt30" “>” "<"/span">" "<"img rc="/zenius61\images\com\btn_tab_root.gif" ">"
```

I need a javascript regular expression which will return the '30' in "ic_evt30"

Comment: if you are looking for digits..`\d+` will do..

Comment: try a regex like `/[\d]+$/` which will give digits at the end

Answer (score 0):

Your request is not clear.
If you are looking for the number at the end of the class name, try the following regex: `class=\"\w*?([0-9]*)\"`, otherwise please clarify.